# JUnit report to show test functionality, not coverage

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, test-coverage, mutation-testing

One of the problems of a team lead is that people on the team (sometimes even including myself) often create JUnit tests without any testing functionality.

It's easily done since the developers use their JUnit test as a harness to launch the part of the application they are coding, and then either deliberately or forgetfully just check it in without any assert tests or mock verifies.

Then later it gets forgotten that the tests are incomplete, yet they pass and produce great code coverage. Running up the application and feeding data through it will create high code coverage stats from Cobertura or Jacoco and yet nothing is tested except its ability to run without blowing up - and I've even seen that worked-around with big try-catch blocks in the test.

Is there a reporting tool out there which will test the tests, so that I don't  need to review the test code so often?

I was temporarily excited to find [Jester](http://jester.sourceforge.net/) which tests the tests by changing the code under test (e.g. an if clause) and re-running it to see if it breaks the test.

However this isn't something you could set up to run on a CI server - it requires set-up on the command line, can't run without showing its GUI, only prints results onto the GUI and also takes ages to run.

Comment: Can you provide a specific example of exactly what you are trying to catch?  That is, an example where the code coverage of the test is high, but the quality of the test is poor.

Comment: Can't you add a check to the code review checklist which checks unit-tests for asserts and actually testing something? I think automated solutions are way to complex for this problem, but a simple extra step in the process might be more then sufficient to learn and prevent this situation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[PIT](http://pitest.org) is the standard Java mutation tester. From their site:

> Mutation testing is conceptually quite simple.
>
> Faults (or mutations) are automatically seeded into your code, then your tests are run. If your tests fail then the mutation is killed, if your tests pass then the mutation lived.
>
> ...
>
> Traditional test coverage (i.e line, statement, branch etc) measures only which code is executed by your tests. It does not check that your tests are actually able to detect faults in the executed code. It is therefore only able to identify code the is definitely not tested.
>
> The most extreme example of the problem are tests with no assertions. Fortunately these are uncommon in most code bases. Much more common is code that is only partially tested by its suite. A suite that only partially tests code can still execute all its branches (examples).
>
> As it is actually able to detect whether each statement is meaningfully tested, mutation testing is the gold standard against which all other types of coverage are measured.
>
> The quality of your tests can be gauged from the percentage of mutations killed.

It has a corresponding [Maven plugin](http://pitest.org/quickstart/maven/) to make it simple to integrate as part of a CI build. I believe the next version will also include proper integration with Maven site reports too.

Additionally, the creator/maintainer is pretty active here on StackOverflow, and is good about responding to tagged questions.

Comment: I obviously don't go to enough devcons because I could have used `PIT` a long time back. I successfully ran the report overnight - 1 hour 30 mins, so definitely not triggering that with every source code check-in. I then checked around to see what level coverage was good and found (now that I am using `mutation testing` as a search term) that [90% is desirable](http://dev.theladders.com/2013/02/mutation-testing-with-pit-a-step-beyond-normal-code-coverage/). So we've got a way to go yet on this project.....

Comment: Yeah, it's a slow process. What you could do is create a separate Maven profile with some filters applied so that PIT only looks at the "danger zones" - packages you're particularly concerned about - and that one run more regularly on your machine, separate from the nightly build.

Comment: The way I recommend it is used is (primarily) locally as the code is changed. If the codebase is large use the version control integration to analyse just the modified files, or use the filters to reduce the scope.

Comment: @henry I forgot about the VCS integration (haven't used it myself yet)! Good point

Answer (score 2):

As far as possible, write each test before implementing the feature or fixing the bug the test is supposed to deal with. The sequence for a feature or bug fix becomes:

1. Write a test.
2. Run it. At this point it will fail if it is a good test. If it does
   not fail, change, replace, or add to it.
3. When you have a failing test, implement the feature it is supposed
   to test. Now it should pass.

Comment: Actually this addresses another point which I often mull over - at the start of a project, how can you write a good test (your point 2) when most of the classes don't even exist which you need to test? I would love to write the tests myself that the developers need to fulfil.

Comment: @Adam Even when doing solo programming, I often write unit tests and Javadoc comments in parallel. Writing unit tests makes me ask questions, like "What should happen if that argument is null?", which should be answered in the comments.

Comment: Good question asked by op.  Good answer by Patricia.  If you really want to get serious on Unit Testing then try pushing it up in the cycle more and more until you get to writing tests first!  The tests are by definition the specifications and proper permutations of them prove everything is working a the method layer as intended.  No coding before tests are written.

Answer (score 2):

You have various options:

- You probably could use some code analysis tool like checkstyle to verify that each test has an assertion. Or alternatively use a JUnit Rule to verify this, but both is easily tricked and works only on a superficial level.
- Mutation testing as Jester does is again a technical solution which would work, and it seems @Tom_G has a tool that might work. But these tools are (in my experience) extremely slow, because the work by *changing the code, running tests, analyzing result* over and over again. So even tiny code bases take lots of time and I wouldn't even think about using it in a real project.
- Code Reviews: such bad tests are easily caught by code reviews, and they should be part of every development process anyway.

**All this still only scratches on the surface.** The big question you should ponder is: why do developers feel tempted to create code just to start a certain part of the application? Why don't they write tests for what they want to implement, so there is almost no need for starting parts of the application. Get some training for automated unit testing and especially TDD/BDD, i.e. a process where you write the tests first.

In my experience it is very likely that you will hear things like: *We can't test this because ....* You need to find the real reason why the developers, can't or don't want to write these tests, which might or might not be the reasons they state. Then fix those reasons and those abominations of tests will go away all on their own.

Comment: Valid points but in my situation you can't be so optimistic about the abilities of developers who are new to agile / TDD, especially in an environment where the likes of you or I are trying to retro-fit a dinosaur project into agile clothing. Logically people may recognise a principle and be able to talk about it and promise to do it, but actually doing it is harder.

Comment: You're correct that mutation testing is slow - but for adapting an existing project, it's probably fine to just run it as a nightly build rather than on each checkin.

Comment: While I can't claim that mutation testing is fast, modern tools like PIT are literally orders of magnitude faster than the early ones like Jester. It is now entirely practical for real codebases. For example a complete analysis of Joda time with PIT takes about 3 minutes (vs about 48 hours with something like Jester). Even with very large codebases the analysis can be limited to only those sections of current interest (e.g changed files as reported by version control).

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is indeed mutation testing.

Regarding tool support, you might also want to look at the Major
mutation framework ([mutation-testing.org](http://mutation-testing.org/)), which is quite efficient and configurable. Major
uses a compiler-integrated mutator and gives you great control over
what should be mutated and tested. As far as I know Major does not yet
produce graphical reports but rather data (csv) files that you can
process or visualize in any way you want.

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you need to consider a coverage tool like [Jacoco](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/), the [gradle plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html) provides report on coverage.  I also use the [EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/) Eclipse plugin to obtain the same results, but with a fairly nice integration in the IDE.

In my experience, Jacoco has provided acceptable numbers even when there are no-op unit test.  As it seems able to accurately determine the tested code paths.  No-op test get low or 0% coverage scores and the score increase as the test become more complete.

**Update**
To address the down-voter.  Perhaps a more appropriate tool to address this is [PMD](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/).  Can be used in an IDE or build system.  With proper configuration and rule development it could be used to find these incomplete unit tests.  I have used it in the past to find methods missing certain security related annotation in the past.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but it sounds like the tests in the OP weren't no-ops.  They did execute code and thus increased code coverage, however, there were no assertions so whatever the code was doing could be wrong

Comment: Yes, good point.  I guess it could be argued that theses assertion-less tests are still valid, but not 100% effective.  Sounds like something I would encourage my team to address during a code review.